# Android: get location updates without interfering with osmdroid.MyLocationOverlay

Tags: android, location, osmdroid

Android / location:

I would like to receive location updates every 5 seconds.

Should I call the method:

> locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,5000, 0, gpsLocListener)?

It is important for me NOT to interfere with the osmdroid MyLocationManager functionality.
Or should I use the `MyLocationOverlay.onLocationChanged()`, e.g. by inheritance of the MyLocationOverlay class.

If so, how often will it be called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no problem having multiple listeners on the location manager. Each one will get events separately. In fact, if you wanted you could use a new instance of osmdroid's `GpsMyLocationProvider` to feed you location updates. Call `mGpsMyLocationProvider.startLocationProvider(myLocationConsumer)` where `myLocationConsumer` is an instance of `IMyLocationConsumer` that receives and handles gps updates as you wish. You can call `mGpsMyLocationProvider.setLocationUpdateMinTime()` to adjust how often you get updates.